# Second previous item in k2

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

In k2, we can get the previous item's title by `$this->item->previousTitle;`.

How can I get the second previous item's title, i.e. the title of the previous item of the previous item?

Answer (score 0):

**Get the result of $this->item->id using sql query**

*/ Find the index of the current item*

```
$current_index = array_search($current_id, $array);
```

// Find the index of the next/prev items

```
$next = $current_index + 1;
$prev = $current_index - 1;
<a href="<?php echo $array[$id + 1]; ?>">Next</a>
<a href="<?php echo $array[$id - 1]; ?>">Prev</a>
```

Comment: I'm clueless as for what to do... More explanation is needed. For example, what `$array` stands for?